# Valid JSON not recognised as object nor array

Tags: android, python, json

I have a query that returns JSON of the format,

```
[["e1", "[{"l1": "A", "l2": "B"}, {"l3": "C", "l4": "D"}]", "1"], ["e2", "[{"l5": "E", "l6": "F"}, {"l7": "G", "l8": "H"}]" , "2"]]
```

A Python list has been dumped to make this JSON. I am told that it is of the format ["label", "JSON", "ID"]. jsonlint.com shows the JSON to be valid but I have no idea how to extract an object/array out of this, parsing it in Android.

I get errors like,

"java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray."

and

"Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject."

How do I parse this query?

Comment: Your second error suggests that you are getting some sort of HTML page back in response to an HTTP request. That is why this site asks for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, which in this case would be Java source code and a complete stack trace. In addition, that JSON is invalid -- try pasting it into jsonlint.com.

Comment: The JSON you included is actually invalid. Copying mistake?

Comment: A great way to test the validity of JSON: Paste it into http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Bruno's answer. The JSON is invalid and even when Bruno made it syntactically valid, it is still not very parseable in Android. JSON is based on key value pairs. Android's implementation of JSON expects that structure. In order to pull even the first array out of that JSON, you would need to specify the key as a String in order to gain access (which that JSON doesn't have). I believe you could still pull values out though by using their keys.

Consider the following which shows you how to create a `JSONObject` from the `String` of JSON corrected by Bruno:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("[[\"e1\", [{\"l1\": \"A\", \"l2\": \"B\"}, {\"l3\": \"C\", \"l4\": \"D\"}], \"1\"], [\"e2\", [{\"l5\": \"E\", \"l6\": \"F\"}, {\"l7\": \"G\", \"l8\": \"H\"}] , \"2\"]]");
    JSONArray parentArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("WHAT IS THIS KEY?");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can't parse even the parent array because there is no key for it and both `getJSONArray()` and `optJSONArray()` expect a `String` key.

If you are simply looking for a `JSONArray` you could instantiate it the same way I demonstrated above just replacing `JSONObject` with `JSONArray`.

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[[\"e1\", [{\"l1\": \"A\", \"l2\": \"B\"}, {\"l3\": \"C\", \"l4\": \"D\"}], \"1\"], [\"e2\", [{\"l5\": \"E\", \"l6\": \"F\"}, {\"l7\": \"G\", \"l8\": \"H\"}] , \"2\"]]");
    //JSONArray parentArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("WHAT IS THIS KEY?");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid.

You have four errors, see the list below and the corresponding fixes.

```
"[{"l1" -> [{"l1"
"D"}]" -> "D"}]
"[{"l5" -> [{"l5"
"H"}]" -> "H"}]
```

The final result is:

```
[["e1", [{"l1": "A", "l2": "B"}, {"l3": "C", "l4": "D"}], "1"], ["e2", [{"l5": "E", "l6": "F"}, {"l7": "G", "l8": "H"}] , "2"]]
```

Hope it helps.